# Java Double overflow

Tags: java, double, overflow, bigdecimal

So basically, I am trying to compute the Likelihood ratio of two things happening together.
The equations are straight enough, but the problem is that my data are rather large and sometimes the middle operations overflow.

I am currently using **double** for my variables, so the up-casting is not possible.
Also the equation has **Logarithm** and **exponential** operators. However I did not find any non-basic mathematical functions for *BigDecimal* or similar types.

In addition, I already tried simplifying the equations as much as possible.

I wonder what are my options here. Here is my code:

```
    c1 = unigramsInfo.get(w1)[0];
    c2 = unigramsInfo.get(w2)[0];
    c12 = entry.getValue()[0];
    N = additionalInfo.get("tail")[1];

    p = c2 / N;
    p1 = c12 / c1;
    p2 = (c2 - c12) / (N - c1);

likelihood = - 2 * ( c2 * Math.log(p) + (N - c2) * Math.log(1 - p)
             - c12 * Math.log(p1) - (c1 - c12) * Math.log(1 - p1)
             - (c2 - c12) * Math.log(p2) 
             - (N - c1 - c2 - c12) * Math.log(1 - p2) );
```

The *N* here could be as big as ten million and the probabilities could become as small as 1.0E-7.

Comment: Maybe you need [BigDecimalMath](https://java.net/projects/omskjug/sources/svn/content/trunk/OpenAHP/src/arithmetic/BigDecimalMath.java?rev=199).

Comment: extend `bigdecimal` and implement the required functionality

Comment: "sometimes the middle operations overflow." in take case you have invalid inputs. The values should never be that large. Can you give a realistic example of when it does? note: 1e-7 is not going to cause an overflow for double.

Comment: `Math.log(1e-7)` is `-16.11` not too big.

Comment: Where is the overflow happening?

Comment: `p1 = c12 / c1` will overflow is `c1 == 0` which has to be handled as a special case. also `c1 == N` will also trigger an overflow.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, for your comment. I was over looking this problem, since I only checked 'p' instead of other probabilities. It seems that in here sometimes 'c12 == c1' and 'c12 == c2' can happen, and that's what ruining the equation.

Comment: @JohnBupit The BigDecimalMath class was very interesting. I think that would be a nice tool to have for someone who really have double overflow problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried with you expression (as I don't know origin of **c1**, **c2**, **c12** and **N** I hardcoded theirs values). So hardcoded values look like this:

```
double c1 = 0.1;
double c2 = 0.2;
double c12 = 0.3;
double N = 0.4;
```

And I've got likelihood=**NaN**.

As mentioned in comments above, pay attention to input. First problematic expressions are (you can get overflow here due to division of extra little or big numbers):

```
double p = c2 / N;
double p1 = c12 / c1;
double p2 = (c2 - c12) / (N - c1);
```

Then you calculate logarithms. Actually in my case (with hardcoded values listed above) I got **NaN** in `Math.log(1 - p1)` expression (as it tries to calculate decimal logarithm of negative number - *p1 < 1* when *c1 > c2* - very probable case).

Generally speaking, you can get not only overflow (in extremal cases) but **NaN** as well (even for "sane-looking" input).

The suggestion is to split you long expression into small Java-expressions. And verify each value that can cause **NaN** or overflow before calculation and throw exceptions manually. This will help to localize the cause of problem when you get invalid input.